# Can not get rid of too new NVIDIA driver from initrd

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, initramfs

I run kernel 3.5.0-27-generic on Ubuntu 12.10  <sub>(Pretzlyquantumbear!?)</sub>

Somehow, I have installed Nvidia driver 310.32, and X11 will not start unless I at each boot go and run `make install` in `nvidia-current-updates-304.88`.

How do I get the correct driver, 304.88, into the initrd?

I have tried `update-initramfs -u` to no avail.

It gets kind of old to do, at each reboot:

- Hold Shift to GRUB menu appears
- Select Special boot
- Select Rescue
- Enter root shell
- `remount -n -o remount,rw /`
- `cd /usr/src/nvidia-current-updates-304.88 && make install`
- `logout`
- Select resume boot

Comment: Have you removed driver 310.32?

Comment: @Salem, no how do I do that?

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`? (use paste.ubuntu.com or something similar to post that information)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5713172/  @Salem . It's all 304.88

Answer (score 1):

It seems from here you have two mixed drivers installed:

- 310.X installed manually (with the installer from nVidia website);
- `nvidia-current-updates` from Ubuntu repos.

First of all you will need to uninstall the 310 driver. If you installed it from a .run file downloaded from nVidia website, you can do that using:

```
sudo sh /path/to/NVIDIA-Linux-<version>.run --uninstall
```

After this you can install some driver from the default repositories. If you need to use a 310 driver you can install the experimental one:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-experimental-310
```

despite being named "experimental" I used it for some time and had found no problems at all.

Or you can stay with the 304 driver you already have:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current-updates
```

If after rebooting you still need to compile the driver before each startup, check the following:

- Check you have `dkms` installed: `sudo apt-get install dkms`;
- Check you have the kernel headers needed to compile the module: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
- Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and watch for warnings/errors.